# get {day} value in variable with codeigniter calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, calendar

In my codeigniter calendar I have this template (taken from codeigniter user guide):

```
{table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" id="tabellaPrenotazioni">{/table_open}
{heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}
{heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
{heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
{heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

{heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

{week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
{week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
{week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

{cal_row_start}<tr class="rigaGiorni">{/cal_row_start}
{cal_cell_start}<td class="cellaGiorno">{/cal_cell_start}

{cal_cell_content}<a href="{content}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_content}
{cal_cell_content_today}<div class="highlight"><a href="{content}">{day}</a></div>{/cal_cell_content_today}

{cal_cell_no_content}{day}{/cal_cell_no_content}
{cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="highlight"><b>{day}</b></div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

{cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

{cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
{cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

{table_close}</table>{/table_close}
```

I need to programmatically add somethings to each day according to which day it is, so I need to save {day} value in a php variable. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see calendar library. I think the only way to do that is to create a library that extends calendar one and make my changes in generate() method.

Answer (score 0):

Parsed `{day}` is the same as `echo $day;`, so you can basically substitute it with

```
echo $day + $something;
```

Or anything you wish, you can always work with PHP variables instead of the mustached ones

Comment: But if I put echo $day instead of {day} I get an error that says $day variable is not defined